# MySql on duplicate record UPDATE issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have scenario in which I am inserting a record and I want to update record if the duplicate primary key is encountered.
Now, I have a column X which is not part of primary key. I want my record to get updated IF AND ONLY IF the value of X is different from the one present.

Right now, my record is getting updated even if X is same. How can I write query to achieve update on duplicate only if certain column is different ?
The current query is

```
INSERT INTO table (a, b, c, d, X) values (10, 11, 12, 13, 153.0 ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE parameter_value = NEWX , timestamp = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

In it, [a,b,c,d] is my primary key and X is the value. 
I also want timestamp to remain same if X is same and timestamp to change if X is changed

Comment: Also, I do not want to include X in primary key

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  You say "my record is getting updated even if X is same".  However, that is the reason for `on duplicate key update`.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, when I say record is getting updated, I mean the timestamp column getting changed, X remaining same, I also want timestamp to remain same if X is same and timestamp to change if X is changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the query I required

INSERT INTO fitness_data (a, b, c, d, X) VALUES (10, 11, 12, 13', XNEW) 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE timestamp = IF( X!= VALUES(X), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, timestamp),
 X = XNEW

So timestamp will only be updates if X!=XNEW else, it wont be updated

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to use `on duplicate key update`, then you need an appropriate unique index.  I'm not sure if this is just `X`, or if it is all four columns.  Creating the unique index is easy, something like:

```
create unique index idx_table_x on table(x);
```

or
    create unique index idx_table_a_b_c_d_x on table(a, b, c, d, x);

Then I think this statement will do what yo want:

```
INSERT INTO table(a, b, c, d, X, timestamp)
    values (10, 11, 12, 13, 153.0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = values(a);
```

It will ignore records where the values are the same.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, when I say record is getting updated, I mean the timestamp column getting changed, X remaining same, I also want timestamp to remain same if X is same and timestamp to change if X is changed

Comment: When do you want to insert a new record?  That is what `insert` is used for.

Comment: I posted the answer, trigger was also one way but wanted to avoid it